# Store coredata file outside of documents directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I allow itunes sharing in my application but I noticed that the coredata create sqlite in the document directory

can I change the save of this file to library , if yes how

best regards

Comment: What do you mean by 'the save'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is possible. I made a little helper method which creates a path that is not accessible through itunes. The database will be stored in the library directory, which is included in itunes back ups.

```
- (NSString *)applicationPrivateDocumentsDirectory {
    static NSString *path;
    if (!path) {
        NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        path = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Private Documents"];
        BOOL isDirectory;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDirectory]) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Can't create directory %@ [%@]", path, error);
                abort(); // replace with proper error handling
            }
        }
        else if (!isDirectory) {
            NSLog(@"Path %@ exists but is no directory", path);
            abort(); // replace with error handling
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

and then you would replace

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SomeApp.sqlite"];
```

in the `- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator` method with:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[self applicationPrivateDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SomeApp.sqlite"]];
```